# Integration step for umbraco 11 S3 bucket integration

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, umbraco

Integration step required for umbraco 11 S3 bucket integration

I need an detailed functional steps for implememtation and needed sample code snippets will hep me to achive the problem.

I am following few steps but facing the exception as no region is active